# I want to rewrite my joomla site link

Tags: joomla

I dont have much knowledge about joomla, So my site link is as siteurl/services/digital-antenna-installation-brisbane which I want to redirect or change to siteurl/digital-antenna-installation-brisbane

Can anyone Please help me on that will guide me how should I do it in joomla. What I tried so far is editing the .htaccess file. I did it as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^services/digital-tv-antenna-installation-brisbane$ /digital-antenna-installation-brisbane [R=301,L]
```

but that did not work. can anyone guide me how to do it. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Direct Alias will fix this issue for you:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/direct-alias

Direct Alias, "allows you to control menu item alias and have short SEF URLs without including aliases of parent menu items."